# Close all windows of another app using Accessibility API

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, window, accessibility

I already know how to use the Mac OSX Accessibility API within Objective-C to reposition windows of another running application, without the use of any kind of scripting bridge.

Now, I want to use this same Accessibility API (again, without any scripting bridge) to close all the open windows of another running application.

The code that I want to write in Objective-C should do the same thing as this AppleScript code:

```
tell application "TheApplication"
close every window
end tell
```

I would guess that this is possible, because it's permitted within AppleScript.

Comment: PS: when I say "without any scripting bridge", I mean without NSApplescript calls. I used AXUIElementCopyAttributeValue and related calls to do the non-applescript-based window repositioning, but I can't figure out how to use the AXUI API to do window deletion. The purpose if this question is to see if this can be done without NSApplescript or any other similar Applescript-sending calls. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's my solution ...

```
+(void)closeWindowsOfApp:(NSString*)appName {

    boolean_t result = false;

    if (appName == nil) {
        return;
    }

    ProcessSerialNumber psn;
    psn.highLongOfPSN = 0;
    psn.lowLongOfPSN  = kNoProcess;

    while (GetNextProcess(&psn) == noErr) {

        pid_t pid = 0;

        if (GetProcessPID(&psn, &pid) != noErr) {
            continue;
        }

        AXUIElementRef elementRef = AXUIElementCreateApplication(pid);
        NSString* title = nil;
        AXUIElementCopyAttributeValue(elementRef, kAXTitleAttribute, (CFTypeRef *)&title);
        if (title == nil) {
            continue;
        }
        if ([title compare:appName] != NSOrderedSame) {
            CFRelease(title);
            continue;      
        }
        CFRelease(title);

        CFArrayRef windowArray = nil;
        AXUIElementCopyAttributeValue(elementRef, kAXWindowsAttribute, (CFTypeRef*)&windowArray);
        if (windowArray == nil) {
            CFRelease(elementRef);
            continue;
        }
        CFRelease(elementRef);

        CFIndex nItems = CFArrayGetCount(windowArray);
        if (nItems < 1) {
            CFRelease(windowArray);
            continue;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < nItems; i++) {
            AXUIElementRef itemRef = (AXUIElementRef) CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(windowArray, i);
            AXUIElementRef buttonRef = nil;
            AXUIElementCopyAttributeValue(itemRef, kAXCloseButtonAttribute, (CFTypeRef*)&buttonRef);
            AXUIElementPerformAction(buttonRef, kAXPressAction);
            CFRelease(buttonRef);
        }

        CFRelease(windowArray);
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Pressing button NSAccessibilityCancelButtonAttribute can be useful as well in some cases if close is not defined. Also sending action kAXCancelAction sometimes may help.

Answer (score 2):

There's a Cocoa class, [`NSApplescript`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSAppleScript_Class/Reference/Reference.html), that lets you compile and run Applescript from within your ObjC code. You haven't really said why you don't want to use AS. Since you've already got the script that does what you want, you can make your program work right now and just use it:

```
NSApplescript * as = [[NSApplescript alloc] initWithSource:@"tell application \"TheApplication\"\nclose every window\nend tell"];
NSDictionary * errInfo;
NSAppleEventDescriptor * res = [as executeAndReturnError:&err];
if( !res ){
    // An error occurred. Inspect errInfo and perform necessary actions
}

[as release];
```

Worry about ideological purity or performance later.

Comment: Thank you very much, but I know I can do it that way. When I said that I don't want to use a scripting bridge, I meant that I'm looking for a non-NSApplescript way to accomplish this. The way I do the window-repositioning involves AXUIElementCopyAttributeValue calls, but I can't figure out how to do the window deletion using this AXUI API. Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: I understand what you said, but you haven't provided any reason for not wanting to use AS, and I'm questioning that desire.

Comment: My desire is to write a non-Applescript-related framework for accomplishing these kinds of tasks. This is partly as a learning experience. I already built a package which contains a nice routine for repositioning windows, solely using the AXUI API, and I want to add to this package of mine to accomplish window deletion, as well.

Comment: I just discovered that the AXUI API can be used to get a reference to a window's "Close" button, and I think that I can do something like this to close each window: AXUIElementPerformAction(button,kAXPressAction) ... where "button" is that Close button. I'm going to test this now.

Comment: @Hippo: You're free (and indeed _should_) post the solution you've worked out, as an Answer. It may be useful to future readers. (As a new user, you may be forced to wait a few more hours, though.) In a day or so you'll also be able to mark it as your "accepted answer".

Comment: Yes, I have to wait a few hours. I'll post my solution tomorrow. Thank you.